# "Neither wonder" - is it a thing?

Tags: phrases, expressions

In response to a surprising realisation, one might say something like **"No wonder {x} is {y}"**. However for a great deal of my life I was apparently erroneously saying **"Neither wonder"** in place of **"No wonder"**. I was absolutely convinced the two were interchangeable.

I was corrected eventually (surprised it took so long for me or anyone else to notice) and now force myself to say **"No wonder"** but I still feel inclined to say **"Neither wonder"** as a quick-fire retort in conversations.

As a native English speaker, well into adulthood now, I wonder:

1. Is **"Neither wonder {x} is {y}"** actually incorrect? (I am assuming so)
2. Is there some related wording I could have been mixing it up with? (With the exception of **"No wonder"**)
3. Where might I have picked this up from? (I'm stumped)
4. Has anyone else ever said this in the history of anything?

Comment: [Google Books Ngrams for *neither wonder*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neither%20wonder%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) may provide insights.

Comment: You are free to use any phrase you like that appeals to you. We all have foibles and idiosynchrasies in our speech, and some people even cultivate them.

Comment: @tchrist I suppose it is entirely possible I gleaned it from the start of a sentence like "Neither wonder or {x}" and just assumed it meant "No wonder" by accident maybe
Thanks :D

Comment: @Weather Vane I never thought about it that way - however I feel this is not one I'll be cultivating as often there are more than 2 outcomes one may be wondering about so either/neither usually doesn't apply

Comment: Nor should you/I wonder. Neither should you/I wonder.  Neither you/I wonder. Neither wonder. No wonder. I buy the Scottish, but I can see how this could evolve independently. The sense of something not being inexplicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a thing, and it appears to be a Scottish thing.

Search `”neither wonder you”` for examples. Here are a few:

> Neither wonder you’re so pleased Sjoerd!! That’s a whole heap of
> beans.
>   <sub>[—eileen / Resident Taxonomist / Location:
> Scotland](https://www.gardenstew.com/threads/theyre-in.10531/)</sub>

> “ . . . That’s scary,” the Scotsman commented. “Neither wonder
> you’re jumpy.”
>  <sub>[*The Heights*, Jim
> Cunningham](https://books.google.com/books?id=sou8X_rvKcgC&pg=PA231&lpg=PA231&dq=%22neither+wonder+you%22&source=bl&ots=s0KI9pyA6f&sig=ACfU3U1JJC8pOHVeB100MSqbXgu_1m-Olg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4x5iGj9j3AhU4J0QIHf2YAA8Q6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22neither%20wonder%20you%22&f=false)</sub>

> It was indeed therefore a most remarkable feat that you were able to
> keep apace with them on your bike – that same one that you used to
> deliver the milk! Neither wonder you were to suffer asthmatic attacks
> throughout your life!
>  <sub>[Archives, Box & Fiddle — The magazine
> for Scottish music
> enthusiasts](https://boxandfiddlearchive.weebly.com/bobby-colgan.html)</sub>

Comment: This explains a lot - my mother was Scottish.

I thank you for this knowledge